# What does the below mean in logback's logger?

Tags: logback, spring-logback

I would like to know what the logger prefix below means in logback logger & Spring framework.
(Logback 1.2.10, Spring is 5.2.19)

Group A

```
[o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory]
[o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource]
[o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate]
[o.s.web.context.ContestLoader]
```

Group B

```
[o.m.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean]
[o.m.s.t.SpringManagedTransaction]
[o.a.v.spring.SpringResourceLoader]
```

I deployed the same war file to two servers with the same environment.
However, Group A (starting with "[o.s") log was not wrote on one server.
(The other server was wrote.)

I would like to know the meaning of `[o.s` in logback logger.

Also, if anyone has experience with this, please let me know how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The logger names are typically the fully qualified class names of the classes where the logger is created. These names include the package name followed by the class name. They are abbreviated, starting from the left, to make them fit a particular text width. The `o.s.` abbreviation stands for `org.springframework`. And in your Group B, `o.m.` stands for `org.mybatis`.